# Finding files based on the date contained in their filenames

Tags: linux, find, date

In the script below, I ask a user to input a date range and apply that range to filter the result of a `find` command.  The command applies to log files whose names contain a date, as in `filename-YYYYMMDD.gz`. Once identified such files are copied into a new directory.

So far what I have (e.g. with a date range like `-newermt 20190820 ! -newermt 20190826` will not copy files on the 25th or 26th.

UPDATE:

```
#!/bin/bash




#Take input from user

read -p "Enter year (YYYY): " Y
read -p "Enter start month: " SM
read -p "Enter start day: " SD
read -p "Enter end month: " EM
read -p "Enter end day: " ED
read -p "Enter copy destination directory (with absolute path): " new_directory

# pad month and day numbers with zero to make the string 2 character long
SD="$(printf '%02d' $SD)"
SM="$(printf '%02d' $SM)"
ED="$(printf '%02d' $ED)"
EM="$(printf '%02d' $EM)"

# Make sure that the new directory exists
#mkdir -p new_directory

# Place the result of your filtered `find` in an array,
# but, before, make sure you set:
#IFS='\n'  # in case some file name stored in the array contains a space

array=(
        $(find /directory/log/ -name "test.file-*.gz" -execdir bash -c '
            filedate="$(basename ${0#./test.file-} .gz)";
            if [[ $filedate -gt $Y$SM$SD ]] && [[ $filedate -lt $Y$EM$ED ]]; then
                basename $0
            fi' {} \;
         )
      )

# loop over array, to copy selected files to destination directory

for i in "${array[@]}"; do
    # ensure that destination directory has full path
    cp "$i" "$new_directory"
done
```

I understand that the find -newermt command is looking for files modified on the date given and not the filename. If you know of any better way to this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Because you are a new user, allow me to comment that it is not usual for authors to radically change their OP's code in order to reflect an evolving solution. You OP may be edited but that is _generally_ done by **appending** successive _EDIT:_ flags followed by additional info or results of tests, **at the end** of yr OP. Just giving you a heads-up. Is all.

Comment: I don't see the point with your "update". Wouldn't a comment on that answer have been better than to copy the answer into the question. Also, what is the point of copying the answer into your question? You don't seem to refer to anything in particular in the code.

Comment: Hey Cbhihi thank you so much theres better progress now so i see the filter trying to copy the files with the daterange I specify but for some reason I'm seeing this now once its executed for all the files in the range: cp: cannot stat `test.file-20190822.gz': No such file or directory . The good news its it lists ALL the files that are in the date range that I input but it seems its not finding them in the directory... Not sure if its because the filter didnt specify the directory.

Comment: just a quick update, I played around with it and I was able to find a solution... I used the for loop and specified the directory where the filenames that are stored in the array is located and it worked! thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finding files based on the date contained in their filenames**

In case what you mean is *really*  to filter on date in filenames, then you can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter year (YYYY): " Y
read -p "Enter start month number: " SM
read -p "Enter start day number: " SD
read -p "Enter end month number: " EM
read -p "Enter end day number: " ED
read -p "Enter copy destination directory (with absolute path): " new_directory

# Do some rule-based checking here. I.e. input variables above
# should conform to expected formats...

# pad month and day numbers with zero to make the string 2 character long
SD="$(printf '%02d' $SD)"
SM="$(printf '%02d' $SM)"
ED="$(printf '%02d' $ED)"
EM="$(printf '%02d' $EM)"

# Make sure that the new directory exists
mkdir -p "$new_directory"

# Place the result of your filtered `find` in an array,
# but, before, make sure you set:
IFS=$'\n'  # in case some file name stored in the array contains a space
sdate="$Y$SM$SD"
edate="$Y$EM$ED"

array=( 
        $(find /directory/log -name "filename-*.gz" -execdir  bash -c '
            filedate="$(basename ${0#./filename-} .gz)";
            if (("${filedate:-0}" >= "${1:-0}")) && 
               (("${filedate:-0}" <= "${2:-0}")); then
                echo "$0"
            fi' {} "$sdate" "$edate" \;) 
      )

# loop over array, to copy selected files to destination directory
#for i in "${array[@]}"; do
#    # ensure that destination directory has full path
#    cp "$i" "$new_directory"
#done

# ... or much cheaper than a loop, if you only need to copy...
cp "${array[@]}" "$new_directory"
```

Comment: Hey Cbhihe thanks for the input, so Solution 2 is exactly what I'm trying to do and I tried to run your input and it looks like I'm running into some issues... I'm seeing these lines:

./test.file-20190710.gz: line 1: ${test.file-}: bad substitution (When searching the directory)

cp: cannot stat `test.file-20190710.gz': No such file or directory (When attempting to copy into new directory)

Also that file isnt in the date range that I inputted...Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Comment: I just made some changes to the script and now I'm seeing this message for multiple files, again not in the date range inputted: 

./test.file-20191006.gz: line 2: [: 20191006: unary operator expected

Comment: Thats strange, so when I ran it I got a unary operator expected message so I updated the if statement line and added the double brackets [[ ]] which got rid of that message... But I'm still not able to copy those files into the new directory. the directory where the log files are located includes different files with different filenames but the specific files I'm interested in are the ones in this format: test.file-YYYYMMDD.gz. I also commented out the mkdir line because I already have a directory created. As well as the IFS because none of the files I'm trying to copy have spaces.

Comment: Sorry the directory that I wish to copy the log files into has these permissions: drwx------. Also the echo is not outputting anything since there is also nothing being copied into the new directory. Also yeah that was a mistake but even with the correct matching pattern truncation it still doesnt work. I'm not receiving any error message there just isnt any files being copied or even stored in the array.